# Подключение заголовочных файлов

Tags: g++, c++

Здравия. Начал изучать C++, и столкнулся с проблемой.

Пытаясь подключить заголовочные файлы ядра linux следующей командой

```
g++ -l /{path}/linux-headers-{ver}/linux/include {остальные ключи}
```

Директория успешно подключается, но подключить сам файл получается только так

```
#include "linux/usb.h"
```

При попытке использовать угловые скобки параметр -l видимо игнорится?

В файле usb.h подключение происходит так:

```
#include <{file}.h>
```

И компилятор неистово ругается на какие-то __u{6|16|32}, из-за того что файлы, которые подключает usb.h не найдены.

В чем разница между ковычками и угловыми скобками, и где я накосячил с подключением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Ничего себе у вас начало обучения. Возможно, вам нужно `libusb-dev` вместо прямого подключения заголовков ядра (которые по идее не предназначены для userspace-программ).

Comment: @VladD, сразу в бой =) Во всех хувтах которые нашел, грят используйте linux/usb.h
Установил libusb-dev, ничего в /usr/src/include не появилось, решил забить.
@KoVadim Следую хувтам =)
Официальный мануал директивы читал не раз, вроде понял.

Answer (score 2):

То, что записано в кавычках, вначале ищется в текущей директории, а потом в везде. То, что записано в угловых скобках, ищется в заданных директориях.

Компилятор ругается, потому что не все подключено, что нужно.

Насколько я помню, так просто подключать хеднры ядра нельзя. Для этого нужно выполнить ряд "ритуалов".

С какой целью используются хеднры ядра?